# Cómo iniciar una aplicación al iniciar Windows

Tags: windows

Desearía saber en cuál clave del registro de Windows 10 puedo incluir una aplicación que deseo se ejecute al arrancar el sistema

Comment: Ya intentaste hacerlo desde el Scheduled Task? (Programador de Tareas)

Comment: Es una pregunta interesante. El problema es que hay diferentes formas de abordar la solución. En definitiva todas usan el programador de tareas. La diferencia es que puedes programarla manualmente, por comandos o C++. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/starting-an-executable-on-system-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto puedes realizarlo ; incluyendo la aplicacion o el comando a ejecutar desde el registro (registry) de widows de la siguiente manera:

1)Haciendo Click al botón de Inicio y luego escribir  Ejecutar o presiona (Win + R).
2)  Escribir regedit y navegar hasta cualquiera de estas dos  claves que muestro a continuación  , en las dos puedes crear un nuevo valor de cada donde debes incluir la aplicación  o el comando msdos ,o archivo de lotes a ejecutar cuando se inicie windows

•   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
•   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Una vez ubicada la clave , podrás crear el valor de cadena  dando click arriba de la clave con el botón derecho,  seleccionas la opción nuevo, valor de cadena  y  a ese valor de cadena le asignaras el nombre de la aplicación a ejecutar :

Ejemplo :  Si estas agregando la   aplicación notepad.exe dentro de ese valor de cadena ,puedes llamarla “Notepad”

Y Listo.
Reinicias la Pc y al iniciar se ejecutará la aplicación Notepad.exe

Cualquier duda me informas

Comment: podes ejecutar ficheros .JS si tenes Node instalado?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funcionó correctamente!!